# git add mysubmoduledir "did not match any files" although the submodule has new commits

Tags: git

I have a repo `top` with a submodule in a subsubdirectory `a/sub`.

When I do `git status` in `top`, it shows `a/sub` as `modified:   a/sub (new commits)`.
To include those new commits in a new commit of `top`, I do `git add a/sub`, but that prints

```
$ git add a/sub
fatal: pathspec 'a/sub' did not match any files
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

## Observe where you are

I found the answer to my own question while I was writing it up:
I had performed the `git add a/sub` in directory `top/a/sub` rather than in `top`.